# Proof of Gronwall inequality

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality

Hi I need to prove the following Gronwall inequality 
Let  $I := [a, b]$ and let $u, \alpha: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\beta: I \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ continuous functions. Further let

$$ u(t) \leq \alpha(t) + \int_a^t \beta(s)u(s){\rm d}s$$

for all $t \in I $. Then the inequality
$$ u(t) \leq \alpha(t) + \int_a^t\alpha(s)\beta(s)e^{\int_s^t\beta(\sigma){\rm d}\sigma}{\rm d}s $$

holds for all $ t\in I $.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) has a couple.

Comment: Yes i should have looked before sorry guys...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first look in the forum but anyway:

Let $y(t) := e^{-\int_a^t\beta(\sigma){\rm d}\sigma}\cdot\int_a^t\beta(s)u(s){\rm d}s$. Then
$$y'(t) = \beta(t)e^{-\int_a^t\beta(\sigma){\rm d}\sigma}[u(t)-\int_a^t\beta(s)u(s){\rm d}s] \leq \alpha(t)\beta(t)e^{-\int_a^t\beta(\sigma){\rm d}\sigma}\ .$$
Now integrate and get 
$$\int_a^t\alpha(s)\beta(s)e^{-\int_a^s\beta(\sigma){\rm d}\sigma}{\rm d}s \geq y(t)-y(a) = y(t) = e^{-\int_a^t\beta(\sigma){\rm d}\sigma}\int_a^t\beta(s)u(s){\rm d}s\ ,$$
and then
$$\int_a^t\beta(s)u(s){\rm d}s \leq e^{\int_a^t\beta(\sigma){\rm d}\sigma}\int_a^t\alpha(s)\beta(s)e^{-\int_a^s\beta(\sigma){\rm d}\sigma}{\rm d}s = \int_a^t\alpha(s)\beta(s)e^{\int_s^t\beta(\sigma){\rm d}\sigma}{\rm d}s\ .$$
At last Gronwall inequality follows from $u(t)-\alpha(t) \leq \int_a^t\beta(s)u(s){\rm d}s$ .

Btw you can find the proof in this forum at least twice...

Comment: when finding $y'$ how do you get rid of term $\beta(a)u(a)$ after applying (uv)' into u'v + uv' and Newton Leibniz formula?

Comment: To be honest, I don't see why $\beta$ should be nonnegative in this proof. Can anyone tell me the reason?